# Can SQL Server's SUM aggregate on `int` and `bigint` explicitly allow overflow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there any way to force the SUM aggregates on `int` and `bigint` to explicitly allow overflow?

That is, is there any way to get the queries below to return -2147483648 and -9223372036854775808 respectively,  instead of giving an "Arithmetic overflow" error?

```
select SUM(x) as sumx
from (
    select 2147483647 as x
    union select 1 as x) a;


select SUM(x) as sumx
from (
    select cast(9223372036854775807 as bigint) as x
    union select 1 as x) a;
```

I tried to SET ARITHABORT OFF; and SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;, but that just gives me NULL instead of a number result, so that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Use bigint to sum and then cast down.

Comment: [sql-server-returns-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174353/sql-server-returns-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type)

Comment: Thanks, shawnt, but what about bigint overflows?  I'll modify my example.

Comment: You could do it with a SQLCLR aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps checking against a sum of decimal types would let you get what you need.

```
select case when sumd > 2147483647
    then -2147483648 else cast(sumd as int) end as sumx
from (
    select
        sum(cast(n as decimal(38, 0))) as sumd
    from T
) t
```

This ought to work for `bigint` as well. `decimal(28, 0)` would reduce the space required for storing the intermediate values if complicated query plans involved temporary storage.